# How to add “Where” entry in Google Calendar using Google API Version 2

Tags: c#, google-calendar-api

I am using Google API Version 2 fo .NET to create Google Calendar Entries. How can we set 
"Where" in Google Calendar ?

Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/data/2.0/developers_guide_dotnet.html#CreatingEvents:

> Note that to set the event's location, we must first construct a Where object whose ValueString is the desired location text.